# UV Unwrap to correctly animate ColorRamp node

Tags: uv, node-editor

I am trying to create an array of lamps that would light up one after another in a constant interpolation. The problem is that I can't figure out how to UV unwrap the lamps so that only one lamp would be entirely white at a time, and so that I could animate ColorRamp arrows and move the "light" from one lamp to another. Hope it makes sense.

I tried to unwrap them together and separately but to no avail. Any suggestion would be appreciated

This is what I am trying to achieve
[image]
And this is what I am getting
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can select all your object, switch to *Edit* mode, choose the top orthographic view and unwrap from view:

[image]

Then in the *UV Editor* enable the *Pivot > Individual Origins* and scale down the islands a lot:

[image]

Give your objects this node setup, with a *Separate XYZ*, in order to project a white stripe on the good axis:

[image]

Then animate the *Mapping* node *Location* values so that the stripe moves along the good axis:

[image]